# Foundation Abide validation throws an error even if card number is valid

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation, abide

I am implementing Foundation Abide in the following: http://alessandrosantese.com/abide/index3.html, however even if the card number is correct (tested with my Visa) it still throws an error when you click on submit. This happens if you type the card number in first and than click on submit.

I have overwritten the pattern card with one of my Visa regex that I will be using for my project.

```
<script>
$(document)
  .foundation({
    abide : {
      patterns: {
        dashes_only: /^[0-9-]*$/,
        ip_address: /^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])$/,
        card:/^4(?:[0-9]{12}|[0-9]{15})/
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: What error? If I fill the form and use `45555555555555555555` it does not show any invalid data warnings. BTW that RE is broken for card numbers

Comment: Did you type in the card number first and clicked on submit?

Comment: if you do that you get the red box error

Comment: If you fill all the fields with correct values and after clic on Submit, it's all right.

Comment: @general03 you are right, but you might also have the odd user who will start filling the card number first and if that happens it will throw an error

Comment: And is it the right check because the error message is _An email address is required._ on card number field

Comment: it's the right check as the pattern attribute is set = to "card". The error message is only a static HTML string.

Comment: If you lost focus on this field and clic on submit, the error disappears...

Comment: I find that not very usable to be honest....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65763/discussion-between-general03-and-alex).